# How do you use the boss monster spell respawn

Tags: boss-monster

How are you supposed to use the respawn card. The rules are so vague and there's 2 different ways we tried to approach this. 1 it only affects the cards on top and 2 it affects all cards even the ones built on top of. I've read rules and tried to find a helpful thread somewhere to clarify and to no luck. How the heck does this card work?

[image]

Text on card: "Treat all of your rooms as if they were just built"

Answer (score 1):

Based on Rules for 5th edition, page 5 (Rooms), this would only affect your visible cards.

http://www.brotherwisegames.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Boss-Monster-5th-Edition-Rulebook.pdf

> B. Ability: The rules text of the card is active as
>   long as it is visible and in play.

The Respawn calls for all of your rooms, but technically the text of the rooms that are not visible is not active, so it wouldn't matter if they had just been spawned -- they are not available to trigger the room ability text.